# Getting the right location name using the lat and long information

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

Can we get the correct location using the latitude and longitude information.Actually I am using the below code to get the location details.But in most of the cases I get only the name of the particular highway not the location name.

```
//Annotation

//1.create coordinate for use with the annotation
CLLocationCoordinate2D wimbLocation;
wimbLocation.latitude=latitude;
wimbLocation.longitude=longitude;

Annotation * myAnnotation= [Annotation alloc];

CLLocation *someLocation=[[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:someLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[placemarks objectAtIndex:0] addressDictionary];
    NSLog(@"%@",dictionary);
    addressOutlet=[dictionary valueForKey:@"Street"];
    NSLog(@"%@",addressOutlet);
    City=[dictionary valueForKey:@"City"];
    NSLog(@"%@",City);
    State=[dictionary valueForKey:@"State"];
    NSLog(@"%@",State);

    myAnnotation.coordinate=wimbLocation;
    myAnnotation.title=addressOutlet;
    myAnnotation.subtitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", City, State];


    [self.MapViewC addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
```

Is there any chance to improve the coding to get more accurate location details?Still the problem was not solved.Can any one help me???

Comment: CLGeocoder will provide Street address only for other country except USA. You can use "https://github.com/samvermette/SVGeocoder" to get the place details. It uses Google place API.

Comment: Go to link mentioned above, there is a good description about how to use it into appliction.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting and using the addressDictionary from CLPlacemark, use CLPlacemark itself and access details through its properties (country, postalCode, administrativeArea, etc).

Properties for CLPlacemark are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLPlacemark).

Comment: What changes I have to make in the codings